# How to count checked chekcbox in current divs and display number

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

i have search stack but i dont find full help to my issue.

This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/msx20/xprc2/1/ and what i want to do ...
I want to count only checked checkboxes in each of accordion divs, and display the number of checked items (i dont want display 0) in the span added by jquery with class 
"accordion_counter" i add "00" value only to show the place. And important for me is tah i want to display checked items for each accordion div, and display te count numer also in the span in tabs into left.

i have tried this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
            $(this).change(updateCount);
        });

        updateCount();

        function updateCount() {
            var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();

            $(".count").text(count);
            $(".count").toggle(count > 0);
        }
});
```

But this count all the checked inputs .... maybe this is the stupid question but i dont have big jquery skills. Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: Try checking out jquery .closest method (http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need jquery [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

```
$('#group_subgrup_1 input:checked').length; 
$('#group_subgrup_2 input:checked').length;
```

and so on..

group_subgrup_1, group_subgrup_2 being the accordion containers. So that only count of each checkboxes are considered.

So in your general click/change function, you can simply call the above and get the individual counts and display wherever you want.

So basically :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
        $(this).change(updateCount);
    });

    updateCount();

    function updateCount() {

    var count1 = $('#group_subgrup_1 input:checked').length; 
    var count2 = $('#group_subgrup_2 input:checked').length;
```

...

```
    $(".count1").text(count1);
    $(".count2").text(count1);
```

and so on..

```
    }
});
```

Hope you get the idea..

Answer (score 1):

try to remove this:

```
       $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
            $(this).change(updateCount);
        });
```

and insert this:

```
       $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
            updateCount();
        });
```